# Tramp remote login with a \ qualified username (escape problems)

Tags: tramp, ssh, remote

I have a remote server I log in to from the command line using either:

```
ssh 'GROUP\user'@host.edu
```

or

```
ssh GROUP\\user@host.edu
```

and it works fine; I've even set up my SSH keys. But I can't figure out how to get this to work with tramp, as the "\" gets sanitized. I've tried using quotes and/or escape slashes, but those don't make it through either. Any solutions?

Comment: Please show exactly what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by using ssh_config, which allows you to bypass all concern about escaping; you just enter your login name in your ~/.ssh/config file and tramp will respect it. I posted full details here: http://www.toryanderson.com/tech/escaped-log-ins-tramp

Answer (score 0):

The link in the accepted answer doesn't work anymore.

A workaround for this issue is to specify only the hostname; tramp will then prompt for the username (and password).